# Error "Unable To Find Table Mapping Or Data Table" when trying to update MSSQL table via datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset, dataadapter

Hi I am using a datagridview to display data from SQL Server, what I want to do is when someone edited something from any cell in the datagridview the database table will also be updated too. My code for populating the datagridview is this:

```
    Dim datest As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblPayMTC", strcon)
    Dim cbtest As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(datest)
    Dim dstest As DataSet = New DataSet
    datest.Fill(dstest)
    dg1.DataSource = dstest.Tables(0)
```

when button is clicked i use this code:

```
    datest.Update(dstest)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line too...

dg1.DataMember = "tblPayMTC"

Comment: Now it throws an error "Child list for field tblPayMTC cannot be created."